# How to change <H1> tag in the WooCommerce product page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, heading

How can I change the product title h1 tag in woocommerce? I already have a h1 tag on my page and want the product name to be h2.

the current title comes from:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary_single_title' );
```

Comment: Shouldn't the file be copied into woocommerce/templates/single-product/title.php and NOT woocommerce/single-product/title.php? NOTE: No... "templates" folder does NOT need to be in path in the child theme. The reason I asked the previous question is due to my changes not appearing in front end due to browser cache. When in doubt go "incognito"!

Answer (score 5):

> You can override the default WooCommerce `title.php` template by your
>   own theme.

Copy `woocommerce/templates/single-product/title.php` and paste it into your active theme under woocommerce/single-product/title.php

Change this line `the_title( '<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>' );` to `the_title( '<h2 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">', '</h2>' );`

*The code is tested and fully functional.*

---

Reference

- [Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Thanks, I also faced same problem and it's work for me.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. Is there a way to do this using a filter preferably, but acceptably an action hook?

Comment: @StephenSabatini: I did't find any action hook or filter for this, till now.

Answer (score 3):

I came here searching for answer, but I like to do things using Filters or Action Hooks. After bit of search, I found a way to do the same thing with Action Hook.

Copy following code to Child Theme 'functions.php'

```
//* Change Woo Product H1 Tag to H3
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'sgl_template_single_title', 5 );
function sgl_template_single_title() {
    the_title( '<h3 class="product_title entry-title">', '</h3>' );
}
```

This will change the H1 Tag in the Product Title shown in Single Product pages to H3. I'm using this code snippet on my project and works great.